# Unicode URL = Could not initialize an instance of the type 'Foundation.NSUrl': the native 'initWithString:'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to open a url in UIWebView that contains unicode characters:

```
var jrURL = new NSURL("http://δπθ.gr");
```

Results in:

```
Could not initialize an instance of the type 'Foundation.NSUrl': 
the native 'initWithString:' method returned nil.
It is possible to ignore this condition by setting
MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.
```

Ones like https://Google.com work fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IDN Domain names like:

- [http://δπθ.gr](http://%CE%B4%CF%80%CE%B8.gr)

Have to be converted (punycode based) in order to be use with `NSUrl`:

- http://xn--pxaix.gr

IDN : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name

Punycode : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode

You can use `System.Globalization.IdnMapping` to convert your domain names to `Punycode` and 
this Namespace/Class is available in `Xamarin.iOS` and `Xamarin.Android`.

```
var idn = new System.Globalization.IdnMapping ();
var dotnetURI = new System.Uri ("http://δπθ.gr);
Console.WriteLine (dotnetURI.ToString());
NSUrl nsURL = new NSUrl (dotnetURI.Scheme, idn.GetAscii (dotnetURI.DnsSafeHost), dotnetURI.PathAndQuery);
Console.WriteLine (nsURL.ToString());
WebView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(nsURL));
```

MSDN `IdnMapping.GetAscii`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.idnmapping.getascii(v=vs.110).aspx

**Note:** `System.Uri.IdnHost` which handling punycode conversions is a part of .Net 4.6 and is not currently available in the Xamarin's `System` namespace

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.idnhost(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: IS there any native iOS function?

Comment: Surprising there is not, Safari/Webkit has this function builtin but it is not available via any SDK that I know if, Here is a punycode converter written in  ObjC that you could wrap into a static library and bind it with sharpie (https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/NSURL-IDN) but using the .Net based  one is "easier"

Comment: Wow, rare case when .NET worked better on Xamarin the Native SDK.

Answer (score 9):

```
var jrURL = new NSURL(new System.Uri("http://δπθ.gr").AbsoluteUri);
```

Easy! (-: